# Drag and Drop into Shopping Cart by simply calling the already programmed onClick event from the Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am simply trying to add a drag and drop functionality to my webshop.

I already programmed a button to each product ("Add to Cart") and once the jQuery `onClick` event starts

```
$(".cartButton").click(function () { ...
```

All the logic for the shopping cart is already programmed, using a couple of ajax calls and so on.

Now my question: I would like to drag the `<img>`(image) of the product onto the `<div>` of the shopping cart but nothing should happen with the layout and nothing in special should be programmed.

The `<img>` stays at its original place and only the exact same stuff as if I would have pressed the button should be triggered.

Is there an easy way to link the drop event with the button click event? maybe even by using html and javascript only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below solution.

If your application is going to be JS heavy, I recommend using a javascript library. I prefer jquery, but there are many more libraries for doing this.

The functionality you are looking for is available in the jQueryUI project as a widget `http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/`

Some people might find it distasteful that I'm recommending a framework, but it will get the job done quicker for you.

Have a look at this example on the files needed to setup a demo `http://jsbin.com/ejolo6`

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I just hoped there would have been an even easier trick.